Visual Studio no me deja escribir código
Estoy segura de que es un error básico de la configuración. Al tener asociado Visual Studio a Unity, cuando hago doble clic en el script que quiero crear, se abre el documento en Visual Studio, pero éste no me deja escribir en el código.
El cursor navega por el código, pero no escribe.

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
